# Date of command in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am using Debian and other people are using this same computer too. I need to know the date of each command were performed in this computer to discover who used it.

Do someone know which command that I can use to discover it?

I'm sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Are you all logging in with the same shell and the same user name and password, or do you each have your own account?

Comment: This may be helpful, from the AskUbuntu forum: http://askubuntu.com/a/634670/547810

Comment: I have already tried this but only few commands appear with the right hour... I think that the commands before I have wrote `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "` are all with the same hour

Comment: @vielmetti we are with different users but I know the keyword

Answer (score 1):

The `history` command might be what you are looking for.

In the `bash` shell, the history is generally stored in the `$HOME/.bash_history` file. The command `help history` will be useful if that is your shell.

If you have accounting turned on, the `lastcomm` command would be useful to look at; but you probably don't have accounting turned on.

If you just want to know who was logged in at a certain time, the `last` command is helpful too.

Comment: this command `last` was very helpful, thank you.


`lastcomm` command was not found in my system.


`$HOME/.bash_history` didn't appear the date like I need.

Answer (score 1):

[Auditing.](https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/)

> **Configuring and auditing Linux systems with Audit daemon**
>
> The Linux Audit Daemon is a framework to allow auditing events on a
>   Linux system. Within this article we will have a look at installation,
>   configuration and using the framework to perform Linux system and
>   security auditing.
>
> **Auditing goals**
>
> By using a powerful audit framework, the system can track many event
>   types to monitor and audit the system. Examples include:
>
> - Audit file access and modification
>
>   - See who changed a particular file
>   - Detect unauthorized changes
> - Monitoring of system calls and functions
> - Detect anomalies like crashing processes
> - Set tripwires for intrusion detection purposes
> - Record commands used by individual users

This is the kind of thing auditing is *designed* to do.